# Search postgresql database for strings contianing specific words

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-like

I'm looking to query a postgresql database full of strings, specifically for strings with the word 'LOVE' in - this means only this specific version of the word and nothing where love is the stem or has that sequence of characters inside another word. I've so far been using the `SELECT * FROM songs WHERE title LIKE '%LOVE%';`, which mostly returns the desired results.

However, it also returns results like `CRIMSON AND CLOVER`, `LOVESTONED/I THINK SHE KNOWS (INTERLUDE)`, `LOVER YOU SHOULD'VE COME OVER` and `TO BE LOVED`, which I want to exclude as they are specifically the word `'LOVE'`.

I know you can use `SELECT * FROM songs WHERE title = 'LOVE';`, but this will obviously miss any string that isn't exactly `'LOVE'`. Is there an operation in postgresql that can return the results I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that looks for `love` either with a space before or after, or if the word is at the start or end of the string:

```
with songs (title) as (
  values 
     ('Crimson And Clover'),
     ('Love hurts'),
     ('Only love can tear us apart'),
     ('To be loved'),
     ('Tainted love')
)
select *
from songs 
where title ~* '\mlove\M';
```

The `~*` is the regex operator and uses case insensitive comparison. The `\m` and `\M` [restrict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE) the match to the beginning and end of a word.

returns:

```
title                      
---------------------------
Love hurts                 
Only love can tear us apart
Tainted love
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/EUTHKM33922

Comment: So I'm trying to run this select * from songs where title ~* ''\mlove\M''; and I'm getting 'Invalid command \mlove'. Do I also need to run the with songs (title) as (
  values ... bit to make this work?

Comment: The `with` is only there for some sample data. There was a typo: there were too many `'` in my query - I fixed that.